# MAX_TOKEN_VAL error in bq command line

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to bq command line, trying to run a simple query that works in UI...

```
bq query “select Email_Address from Contact.mailchimp_unsubscribe”
```

I get this error:

> Error in query string: Error processing job
>   'aaa-dataplatform:bqjob_r41894edbc8642323_00000161bebe6574_1':
>   Encountered "  "\u201c "" at line 1, column 1.
>   Was expecting: < EOF >

If I change the column name Email_Address to `*` the query works. However, I will need to make this an append query with a specific column list. So, need to figure out how to make the column list work.

Comment: have you tried it in BQ UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u201c is a left double quotation mark; error message also says that it's at the line 1, column 1. So the quotation mark is passed to BQ with the query text. In the command line, try using neutral double or single quotation.

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much. I was drafting a google doc with instructions for someone, and didn't notice the change in quotes. I'll stick to the simple text editors from now on.